# Operating with Container correctly in TabBar (for autorization)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my app i'm using tabBars, for authorization I decided to using Container - if this is the first start: I'm showing it.

[image]

I have several questions which I can't understand. The first question is - how to set imageBackground for UIView, I'm trying:

```
 //Autorization.m
 -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame
 {
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 self.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
 return self;
 }
```

But it doesn't work (In UIView is upsent self.view.backGroundColor).
And how can I send message to Container? I'm trying control drag it, but it doesn't work. For example I have to set Container hidden if authorization success that I was able to see the main. In main view a need to set all UI elements hidden until Container disappeared, there is no another solution?
And the last question is not particularly important, how to make that when the authorization is successful, this scene has risen up and disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use a container for your problem. Just set a modal segue from `FirstViewController` to `AuthorizationViewController` and launch the segue yourself at the start in `FirstViewController` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (thisIsTheFirstTimeThisViewGetCalled)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalSegueToAuthorization" sender:self];

    // Do some other stuff
}
```

For you information, a Container is used to fuse views together and have several viewControllers controlling the same view. What you want here is show a view just once (until the user is authenticated).